# Pass variables to a dynamic Controller inside a Directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got a directive that **loads a different template** depending on the variable **type** that is passed to it. I pass to the isolated scope of the directive the variables **patient** and **service** too.

```
.directive('serviceCharts', serviceCharts);

function serviceCharts() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      if(attrs.type) {
         scope.template = 'views/' + type + '.html';
    }
    attrs.$observe('type', function (type) {
      if(attrs.type) {
        scope.template = 'views/' + type + '.html';
      }
    });
  },
  template: '<div ng-include="template"></div>',
  scope:{
    patient:'=',
    service:'='
  }
};
```

}

In the **template** (views/myservice.html for example) I load the **controller**:

```
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm"> 
     VIEW
 </div>
```

And in the controller (myCtrl) I **access** to the **patient and service** this way:

```
  service = $scope.$parent.$parent.service;
  patient = $scope.$parent.$parent.patient;
```

This works fine, but I don't like this way of accessing the variables via the $parent.$parent. This is messing with my tests too.

Is there another (better) way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a wrapper object for `patient` & `service` properties. That can be named as `model` & then provide that model object to your directive.

Then problem with your current approach is, `ng-include` create a child scope for `template` which it renders in it. So as your passing primitive type object binding to directive, If you are changing any of child primitive type binding in child scope. It loses a binding that's why tend to using `$parent.$parent` notation exactly bind to original source object.

```
$scope.model = {
  patient:'My Patient',
  service:'My Service'
};
```

By making above object structure will ensure you're following `Dot Rule`. Usage of `Dot Rule` will avoid `$parent.$parent` explicit scope annotation.

Directive scope binding will changed down to below

```
scope:{
   model:'='
}
```

And directive usage will look like below

```
<service-charts type="{{'sometype'}}" model="model"></service-charts>
```

---

---

The other alternative than Dot Rule to such kind of scoping related issue is follow `controllerAs` pattern. But then as you are gonna use isolated `scope` with `controllerAs` you should make `bindToController: true` option to true for making sure all the `scope` are merged down to controller context.

```
scope:{
    patient:'=',
    service:'='
},
controllerAs: '$ctrl',
bindToController: true
```

And then use `$ctrl` before each directive scoped variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I didn't know the "bindToController: true", this looks prominsing! I'm aware that ng-include is not a good solution, but i need a dynamic controller too, changing for the different "type", and the "controller" option of the directive doesn't allow me to use an expresion. Do you know how could I change the controller depending on the "type" variable?

Comment: Could you provide me a pluker.. suggested solution should work AFAIK

Comment: Thanks, I'm on it :)

Comment: Ok, my code now is something like this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ryuBp6UjH4xBHlRm8lYf?p=preview

Can you do something to improve the way I pass the variables and define the controller (so I can remove the ng-include) but with the controller depending on the value of type?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I pressed the Enter key before I could finish :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way to do this. You should use [`services`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) and store variables in those services (in your case you should create a factory for storing data). Then you can inject those services and access their data.

**Sidenote:**
You can use `{ ..., controller: 'controllerName', controllerAs: 'vm' }` syntax in your directive so you do not need to declare those in your html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, services are the way to store this variables, but at least I need the ids of the "patient" and "service" that I got from the route.
And you are right about the controller: and controllerAs too, but can I make these dynamic changing with the value of "type"?

Comment: @Luisma depends on what sets those templates. In most of the cases I would suggest using a router which would display different templates based on a route. Also, as Pankaj mentioned, a plunker would really help.